# text area height increases when overflow scroll is applied

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I have a html textarea input and a div directly below it. Whenever I set overflow to scroll to the textarea the height increases the distance between the textarea and the label adding too much space. Is there anyway to prevent the height increasing and still have the overflow with the div closely below the textarea?

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

 const CommentField = styled.textarea`
      background: transparent;
      border: none;
      outline: none;
      padding: 0px;
      overflow: scroll;
      resize: none;
    `;

 const Comment = () => {
    
       return( <CommentField
                id="comment"
                name="comment
                placeholder="Add your comment here"
                cols={30}
                rows={1}
              /> 
            <div>date / time </div> )

}

export default Comment;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
textarea {
  resize: none;
}
```

Let us know if this is the desired answer.

**EDIT**
Solution proposed above was tried by OP with no improvement.

You might want to set a fix height with the desired values such as :
Then you should define an height and max-height to fix this to desired value.
Like so:

```
textarea{
  background: transparent;
      border: none;
      outline: none;
      padding: 0px;
      overflow: scroll;
      resize: none;
  height:20vh;
  max-height:20vh;
  
}
```

Note that you can also hide the scrollers for better visual result.

Comment: Sorry resize is there. Ive updated it. Still by default the height is increased.

Comment: That just increased the height of the textarea. That's not what i need.

Comment: But is the textarea still increasing in size ?

Comment: I have a text area and a say a div below it, I need the div to sit close below the textarea, but for some reason the overflow: scroll increases the height between the textarea and the div. Sorry should have explained that better. I've updated the question body. See above.

Comment: Probably best i make a new question now.